# Preferring org-cycle to yas-expand when hitting tab

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, yasnippet

If both org-mode and yasnippet are active, tab will expand a snippet if possible and otherwise execute org-cycle.  Is it possible to reverse this priority?

org mode version: 9.0.9.
yasnippet version: qb-85-ge99b283-dirty.